# How to select only one dropdown and disable all other with respect to radio button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

There is a course, and every course happens on a specific date range.

Now if I Select course 1 only course 1 dates should pass when I click submit button
and all other course dates should get disabled.

[image]

HTML code

```html
            <ul class='table_course_list'> 

                    <li class="inside_course_list"> <!-- For Checkbox -->
                        <label class="checkboxContainer" for="course_1">
                            <input type="radio" id="course_1" name=course_name value="00011">
                            <span class='checkmark'>course_1 </span>
                        </label>
                        <select id="course_date" class="box" name="course_date">
                            <!-- <option selected>Choose ....</option> -->
                            <option selected=selected disabled>PLease select objects</option>

                            <option value="1">Jan. 7, 2020 - Aug. 6, 2020</option>

                            <option value="2">May 13, 2020 - May 16, 2020</option>

                            <option value="3">June 1, 2020 - June 13, 2020</option>

                        </select>
                    </li>

                    <li class="inside_course_list"> <!-- For Checkbox -->
                        <label class="checkboxContainer" for="course_2">
                            <input type="radio" id="course_2" name=course_name value="000022">
                            <span class='checkmark'>course_2 </span>
                        </label>
                        <select id="course_date" class="box" name="course_date">
                            <!-- <option selected>Choose ....</option> -->
                            <option selected=selected disabled>PLease select objects</option>

                            <option value="4">July 1, 2020 - July 15, 2020</option>

                            <option value="5">July 17, 2020 - July 31, 2020</option>

                            <option value="6">July 26, 2020 - Sept. 11, 2020</option>

                        </select>
                    </li>

            </ul>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This is not a code-writing service where you just drop off your requirement so that someone else can make it for you. You are supposed to show your efforts, and give a proper problem description along with them.

Comment: I am fully aware about How to Ask, this is not my first Question, But Yes I am not a frontend developer so it may be possible that I need to provide more information for this respective question, but I gave my best to solve this using javascript but I was not able to do it, therefore I posted here and asked it in a very minimal way.

Comment: That doesn’t change the fact that we want to see your effort first of all! _“But Yes I am not a frontend developer”_ - that also does not mean that we will write code _for you_. If you don’t show us at least your attempt and give us a proper problem description with it, then you have not done the _minimum_ that is expected of you here so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a snippet which works according to your needs, I've explained in comments wherever necessary. Hope it helps you.

```js
$(function() {
  $('[name="course_name"]').on('change', function() { // whenever user changes his selection fire an event

    $select = $('[name="course_date"]');  // select element
    $select.attr('disabled', true);  // make all select disabled(if previously one of them wasn't)
    $(this).parent().siblings('[name="course_date"]').attr('disabled', false); // make the closest one active -- here I've first chose parent({label}) and then its sibling({[name="course_date"]})
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='table_course_list'>

  <li class="inside_course_list">
    <!-- For Checkbox -->
    <label class="checkboxContainer" for="course_1">
    <input type="radio" id="course_1" name=course_name value="00011"><span class='checkmark'>course_1 </span>
    </label>
    <!-- Make the select disabled by default, so the user has to select radio button first -->
    <select id="course_date" class="box" name="course_date" disabled>
      <!-- <option selected>Choose ....</option> -->
      <option selected=selected disabled>PLease select objects</option>
      <option value="1">Jan. 7, 2020 - Aug. 6, 2020</option>

      <option value="2">May 13, 2020 - May 16, 2020</option>

      <option value="3">June 1, 2020 - June 13, 2020</option>

    </select>
  </li>

  <li class="inside_course_list">
    <!-- For Checkbox -->
    <label class="checkboxContainer" for="course_2">
    <input type="radio" id="course_2" name=course_name value="000022"><span class='checkmark'>course_2 </span>
    </label>
    <!-- Make the select disabled by default, so the user has to select radio button first -->
    <select id="course_date" class="box" name="course_date" disabled>
      <!-- <option selected>Choose ....</option> -->
      <option selected=selected disabled>PLease select objects</option>
      <option value="4">July 1, 2020 - July 15, 2020</option>

      <option value="5">July 17, 2020 - July 31, 2020</option>

      <option value="6">July 26, 2020 - Sept. 11, 2020</option>

    </select>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you @sauhardnc for solving this.

Comment: Happy to help, please consider upvoting it if you can. Happy coding. :)